# Pandas count groupbyed elemenys by condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'user': ['1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '3', '3', '3'],
    'value': ['4', '4', '1', '2', '2', '2', '3', '1', '1']
})
```

'value' sorted by date, so i need to count users for which the last element is smaller than the other elements in the group

for this df it would be 2 because last element for group 'user 1' is lesser than other elements from group, same thing for user 3, but user 2 last element is greater thean other elements in group so i dont need to count it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare all values by last one with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and [`GroupBy.last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html) for greater by [`Series.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html), filter values of users by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and last count unique values by [`Series.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nunique.html):

```
#convert values to numeric
df['value'] = df['value'].astype(int)

out = df.loc[df['value'].gt(df.groupby('user')['value'].transform('last')), 'user'].nunique()
print (out)
2
```

EDIT:

It also omit one element groups:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'user': ['1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '3', '3', '3', '4'],
    'value': ['4', '4', '1', '2', '2', '2', '3', '1', '1', '8']
})

df['value'] = df['value'].astype(int)

out = df.loc[df['value'].gt(df.groupby('user')['value'].transform('last')), 'user'].nunique()
print (out)
2
```

Comment: Thanks, its also work if there are couple of groups with only 1 element, isnt?

Comment: @Contra111 - no, because it is no greater, only equal.