# pandas check last groupbyed element

Tags: python, pandas

this question is kinda similar to [Pandas count groupbyed elemenys by condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63261148/pandas-count-groupbyed-elemenys-by-condition)

I have dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'user': ['1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '3', '3', '3'],
    'value': ['4', '4', '1', '2', '2', '2', '3', '1', '1']
})
```

'value' sorted by date, so i need to count users for which the last element is equal to something, for example '1' (it should be string)

for this df it would be 2 because last element for group 'user 1' is '1', same thing for user 3, but user 2 last element is not '1' so i dont need to count it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) with `keep='False'` for last rows of groups by `user`, then check `value` for equality by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) and count `True`s values by `sum`:

```
out = df.drop_duplicates('user', keep='last')['value'].eq('1').sum()
print(out)
2
```

Another idea with [`GroupBy.last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html):

```
out = df.groupby('user')['value'].last().eq('1').sum()
print(out)
2
```

Answer (score 1):

Just get the last value with a groupby and compare

```
df.groupby('user').apply(lambda x:  True if x['value'].iloc[-1]=='1' else False).sum()
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you give this a shot?

```py
df.groupby('user', sort=False).value.apply(lambda vals: vals.iloc[-1] == '1').sum()
```

Output:

```
2
```